# Twitter Emoji Encoding in Python

Tags: python, twitter, unicode, encoding, emoji

I'm scraping tweets from Twitter using ScoutZen and I came across these emoji encodings: "ðŸ™ðŸ»ðŸŒˆðŸ™ðŸ»" = . I want to ask what kind of encoding is this and how can I decode them in Python? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This kind of mistake is called [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). In this case, the original emoji string was encoded with UTF-8, then decoded with Windows codepage 1252. Try this: `''.encode().decode('cp1252', errors='ignore')`. Due to the `errors="ignore"` part, some characters were dropped during decoding, so this is a non-revertible distortion.

Comment: Better to show the code doing the scraping and fix that.  While your can reverse the mojibake in some instances, fixing the source that generated it is a better option.